# Debian server do not reboot when asked to

Tags: debian

**Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)**

We have an issue with our debian server when we initiate a reboot. The system does not reboot that simple.

When we initiate reboot, this is the output in syslog:

```
The system is going down for reboot NOW!
Jul 10 10:11:07 foodb init: Switching to runlevel: 6
Jul 10 10:11:08 foodb mysqld: 140710 10:11:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
Jul 10 10:11:08 foodb mysqld:
Jul 10 10:11:08 foodb mysqld: 140710 10:11:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Jul 10 10:11:10 foodb mysqld: 140710 10:11:10  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jul 10 10:11:12 foodb mysqld: 140710 10:11:12  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 13851421813
Jul 10 10:11:12 foodb mysqld: 140710 10:11:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Jul 10 10:11:12 foodb mysqld:
Jul 10 10:11:12 foodb mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And thats it...

The system seem to run just fine after a reboot has been initiated. Only the mysql service is no longer functional.

**In order to reboot the system, we have to type reboot once again.**

When /sbin/reboot has been initiated the first time, this is the output of ps aux | grep mysql:

```
root@foodb:/home/foodb# ps aux | grep mysql
root      2685  0.0  0.0   4180   704 ?        S    10:23   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     3004  0.4  2.4 418380 50364 ?        Sl   10:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
root      3005  0.0  0.0   4088   640 ?        S    10:23   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
root      3416  0.0  0.0   9456  1596 ?        S    10:25   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/mysql stop
root      3497  0.0  0.0   9456   824 ?        S    10:25   0:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/mysql stop
root      3498  0.0  0.1  34200  2112 ?        S    10:25   0:00 /usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf shutdown
root      3590  0.0  0.0   7832   872 pts/0    R+   10:25   0:00 grep mysql
```

There is something fishy going on with the server. Why do we have to type reboot twice in order to restart the system? We have scheduled reboots that does not work as intended because of this.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason for scheduled reboots? In a properly configured system, there should be no need for scheduled reboots.. Anyway, the problem here is MySQL, it doesn't finish its shutdown procedure correctly, therefore the system is stuck waiting for it to shut down. How long have you waited before typing reboot again? What is your MySQL configuration?

Comment: The MySQL configuration is default, no changes done really. Last time I waited for 4 hours, nothing.

The server runs tasks every night which require a reboot, what tasks I cannot tell for safety reasons. However, it does some mysql work every 30th second daily. Not sure if it would cause this though.